# NRF24L01+PA+LNA (Transciever) not communicating between two arduinos

Tags: arduino-uno, serial-communication

I am using arduino UNO and mega2560.
I used 2 modules NRF24L01.
one is for transmitting and other recieving.
Problem:
I get random values on reciever side of arduino serial monitor.
When I use int type it gives random integers continously.
when I use String type it give random characters.

***Coding:***

```
/*-----( Import needed libraries )-----*/
#include <SPI.h>   // Comes with Arduino IDE
#include "RF24.h"  // Download and Install (See above)
/*-----( Declare Constants and Pin Numbers )-----*/
//None yet
/*-----( Declare objects )-----*/
// (Create an instance of a radio, specifying the CE and CS pins. )
RF24 myRadio (7, 8); // "myRadio" is the identifier you will use in following methods
/*-----( Declare Variables )-----*/
byte addresses[][6] = {"1Node"}; // Create address for 1 
int dataReceived;  // Data that will be received from the transmitter

void setup()   /****** SETUP: RUNS ONCE ******/
{
  // Use the serial Monitor (Symbol on far right). Set speed to 115200 (Bottom Right)
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  //Serial.println(F("RF24/Simple Receive data Test"));
  //Serial.println(F("Questions: terry@yourduino.com"));

  myRadio.begin();  // Start up the physical nRF24L01 Radio
  myRadio.setChannel(108);  // Above most Wifi Channels
  // Set the PA Level low to prevent power supply related issues since this is a
  // getting_started sketch, and the likelihood of close proximity of the devices. RF24_PA_MAX is default.
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  //  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);  // Uncomment for more power

  myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]); // Use the first entry in array 'addresses' (Only 1 right now)
  myRadio.startListening();

}//--(end setup )---


void loop()   /****** LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY ******/
{

  if ( myRadio.available()) // Check for incoming data from transmitter
  {
    while (myRadio.available())  // While there is data ready
    {
      myRadio.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
      //Serial.println("Data is coming");
      // Get the data payload (You must have defined that already!)
    }
  } // DO something with the data, like print it
   else{ 
   Serial.println("Data received = ");
    Serial.println(dataReceived);
delay(200);}

}//--(end main loop )---
```

[Reciever serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdhv8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're potentially calling `myRadio.read()` multiple times with the same destination variable.

This will cause the data already stored in that variable to be overwritten the second time you go through the while loop.